# Did USSR train East Pakistani separatists?

Tags: soviet-union

Here is a video from the defected KGB agent [Yuri Bezmenov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yuri_Bezmenov):

- [Behind Dhaka's fall - Yuri Bezmenov (Ex-KGB Agent)](https://www.dailymotion.com/video/x1wecnm)

The following is the part of the interview I am intersted in:

> ... Most of the Awami League party members, [Awami-leagueians, People's Party](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Awami_League), were trained in Moscow in the [high party school](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Lenin_School). Most of the [Mukti Fauj](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mukti_Bahini) leaders Mukti Fauj in Bengali means People's Army, same as Swapo and all kinds of liberation armies all over the world the same bunch of useful idiots. They were trained at [Lumumba University](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peoples%27_Friendship_University_of_Russia) and various centers of the KGB in Simferopol, in Crimea, and in Tashkent. So when I saw that Indian territory is being used as a jumping board to destroy East Pakistan, I saw myself thousands of so called students traveling through India to East Pakistan, through the territory of India and Indian government pretended not to see what was going on. ...

Did USSR train East Pakistani separatists?

If so, can you supply me with a source?

Comment: The article says most Awami League party members and most Mukti Fauj leaders were trained in Moscow. The latter claim seems implausible if you look at the biographies of  Mukti Fauj leaders, most of whom were trained by the Pakistani army and some in western Europe; the claim about party members seems implausible too due to the raw numbers. However, if you're asking "did the USSR train any East Pakistani separatists?" that is a different question, and in a sense one that's easier to prove true (find one or more trained in Moscow) but harder to disprove (prove none were trained in Moscow).

Comment: @StuartF, *if you look at the biographies of Mukti Fauj leaders, most of whom were trained by the Pakistani army and some in western Europe* --- What is your source?  Mukti Fauj (or Mukti Bahini) was primarily trained in India. However, there is a great debate about their loyalty to the war-time temporary Bangladeshi government. Coz, there was a part of Mukti Fauj called "Mujib Bahini" which was trained by R&AW and is known to engage in rivalry with the non-RAW part of Mukti Fauj personnel.